# Using case_when with multiple vectors

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to use `case_when` to modify/mutate a column based on two separate inputs. One that used to create the LHS logical and the respective input value on the RHS. An example is provided below.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(tibble)

df <- tibble(var = paste0(rep("var", 10), 1:10),
                 label = c("label1", "label2", rep(NA, 7), "label10"))

match_var <- paste0(rep("var", 7), 3:9)
new_labels <- paste0(rep("add_this_label", 7), 3:9)

df %>% 
  mutate(test = map2(match_var , new_labels,
                     ~case_when(
                       var == .x ~ .y,
                       TRUE ~ label
                     )
  ))
```

I think the issue is that within `case_when` everything is evaluated as expression but I'm not completely sure. One can manually type out all 7 lines within `case_when` but my application requires me to accomplish this when the vectors `match_vars` and `new_labels` are very long - making manual typing of `case_when` infeasible.

```
df %>% 
  mutate(label = case_when(
    var == match_var[1] ~ new_labels[1],
    var == match_var[2] ~ new_labels[2],
    var == match_var[3] ~ new_labels[3],
    var == match_var[4] ~ new_labels[4],
    var == match_var[5] ~ new_labels[5],
    var == match_var[6] ~ new_labels[6],
    var == match_var[7] ~ new_labels[7],
    TRUE ~ label
  ))
```

**EDIT**: the desired result can be accomplished using a `for` loop but now I want to know if is this possible using `case_when` and `map2_*` function?

```
for (i in seq_along(match_var)) {
  df$label <- ifelse(df$var == match_var[i], new_labels[i], df$label)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We create a named vector and use that to match the the values in 'var' so as to change the NA elements to 'new_labels'

```
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    mutate(label = case_when(is.na(label) ~ 
                       deframe(tibble(match_var, new_labels))[var], 
         TRUE ~ label))
# A tibble: 10 x 2
#   var   label          
#   <chr> <chr>          
# 1 var1  label1         
# 2 var2  label2         
# 3 var3  add_this_label3
# 4 var4  add_this_label4
# 5 var5  add_this_label5
# 6 var6  add_this_label6
# 7 var7  add_this_label7
# 8 var8  add_this_label8
# 9 var9  add_this_label9
#10 var10 label10
```

NOTE: Instead of using `deframe`, the named vector can be created with `setNames` as well

Comment: this is great! if you don’t mind me asking, could you explain how named vectors work within ‘case_when’? Is it related to NSE?

Answer (score 1):

You can join the new labels to the data frame and fill in with the old label as necessary.

```r
library("tidyverse")

df <- tibble(var = paste0(rep("var", 10), 1:10),
             label = c("label1", "label2", rep(NA, 7), "label10"))

match_var <- paste0(rep("var", 7), 3:9)
new_label <- paste0(rep("add_this_label", 7), 3:9)

new_labels <-  tibble(match_var, new_label)

df %>%
  left_join(new_labels, by = c("var" = "match_var")) %>%
  mutate(new_label = if_else(is.na(new_label), label, new_label))
#> # A tibble: 10 x 3
#>    var   label   new_label      
#>    <chr> <chr>   <chr>          
#>  1 var1  label1  label1         
#>  2 var2  label2  label2         
#>  3 var3  <NA>    add_this_label3
#>  4 var4  <NA>    add_this_label4
#>  5 var5  <NA>    add_this_label5
#>  6 var6  <NA>    add_this_label6
#>  7 var7  <NA>    add_this_label7
#>  8 var8  <NA>    add_this_label8
#>  9 var9  <NA>    add_this_label9
#> 10 var10 label10 label10
```

<sup>Created on 2019-03-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: This is a creative approach using joins I didn’t consider. I might opt for @akrun solution just because I want to avoid joins due to performance but I will test that tomorrow

Answer (score 1):

Since you're comparing the `==` condition, this can also be done with `dplyr::recode` using a named vector (note the need for unquote splicing `!!!`):

```
df %>%
    mutate(
        label = recode(
            var,
            !!!setNames(new_labels, match_var),
            .default = label
        )
    )
```